# Explode labels of a column to create new columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this -

```
ID Col1 Col2 Mon
1   10   20   Jan
1   12   13   Feb
2    2    4   Mar
```

I want to transform this to-

```
ID Col1_jan Col1_Feb Col1_Mar Col2_Jan Col2_Feb Col2_Mar
1   10        0      0         20       0        0
1   0         12     0         0        13       0
2   0         0      2         0        0        4
```

I have used for loops to do so, but it is taking a long time to run as my dataframe is fairly large. How can I do this in more efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `pivot`, which can be done with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
out = (df.set_index(['ID','Mon'], append=True)
         .unstack('Mon', fill_value=0)
      )
out.columns = [f'{y}_{x}' for x,y in out.columns]
out = out.reset_index(level='ID')
```

Output:

```
   ID  Feb_Col1  Jan_Col1  Mar_Col1  Feb_Col2  Jan_Col2  Mar_Col2
0   1         0        10         0         0        20         0
1   1        12         0         0        13         0         0
2   2         0         0         2         0         0         4
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) then condense the `MultiIndex`, then fill missing values with 0 using [`df.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
Out = df.pivot(columns='Mon', values=['Col1', 'Col2']).fillna(0)
Out.columns = Out.columns.map('_'.join)
Out.insert(0, 'ID', df['ID']) 

   ID  Col1_Feb  Col1_Jan  Col1_Mar  Col2_Feb  Col2_Jan  Col2_Mar
0   1       0.0      10.0       0.0       0.0      20.0       0.0
1   1      12.0       0.0       0.0      13.0       0.0       0.0
2   2       0.0       0.0       2.0       0.0       0.0       4.0
```